# How to use git from emacs

Tags: git, emacs

The previous answers on this topic seem out of date so I am asking again in search of more timely info.

I use emacs development sources (24.0.50.1) to build my own emacs. Yes, I drank the Kool-Aid.

I recently started using git to clone development repositories and for my own projects. I want to use of git from within emacs, and I only want to learn one interface.

It appears that vc-git and magit are the leading choices. Is that right?

It looks like vc-git would be the way to go if I often used other VC systems (which I don't), and that magit is the best fit since I only plan to use git.

Does that sound right?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: Update: I have now used both magit & vc-git. I found sanityinc's advice to be right on... namely that they complement each other & you might as well use both... and enjoy

Comment: Two years have passed, and this still shows up near the top in searches for git and emacs - have things changed?  Is vc-git still the way to go?

Comment: @gcbenison Magit is probably the best way to go, although the Egg fork is getting commits recently too, so it's worth grabbing it via Melpa.

Comment: Now, 4.5 years of emacs + git development later, I use emacs+magit for 95% of what I do in git, falling back to the git command line occasionally. About a year ago magit received a complete facelift and a large number of mind-bending changes. It might have been better if the new version was called magit2 rather than being slipstreamed into magit. In any event, now that I have digested the latest magit Kool-Aid I am an even happier camper!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Magit is a wonderful choice because it gives you a good project-level view of your repo and its history, and lets you do neat things like stage/unstage individual diff hunks in the files you've edited. Plus, it's very actively used and maintained.

I personally use vc-git in addition to magit; it's handier than magit for various operations on the current file, e.g. viewing a diff (`C-x v =`), getting the file's history (`C-x v l`) or reverting the file to a pristine state (`C-x v u`).

BTW, magit's home on the web recently changed to this: https://github.com/magit/magit

Comment: Thanks sanityinc. I have now tried out both. I found your advice to be right on. Mark me down as a happy magit + vc-git camper!

Comment: Great! Maybe you want to go ahead and 'accept' this answer then, so that the question is closed?

Comment: The only thing that bugs me about magit is there is no shortcut to do a commit afaik - you need to go into status first.

Answer (score 6):

I use and love Magit. It's easy to [install](https://github.com/magit/magit) on other systems if you need. The commands I use often are:

`C-i` - While having any file open to open up the Magit "changes" window to see my changes to all files. Pressing tab on any filename and I get a colored diff of all changes. Pressing `s` stages them or `k` reverts the file (and any buffers using the file.) `P` to push all my staged changes.

I also see all my `stashes` and can tab on any of them to see a diff, `k` to drop them. All commands are so consistent.

Doesn't get much easier and smooth than that!

Full doc [here](http://zagadka.vm.bytemark.co.uk/magit/magit.html).

Comment: Also, it's available in the marmalade repo

Comment: Also available via Melpa too.

Answer (score 2):

Just have a look here: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Git

IMO Egg, fork of Magit, is good too.

Comment: In my experience magit is nerv wreckingly slow. Have you experienced the same with magit or Egg?

Comment: I really haven't faced any performance issue. My only gripes were with the features

Comment: When was the last time you tried magit? It's been very actively developed, and the last commit to Egg was apparently in early 2009.